# Why Acetoxy group is ortho/para directing although it shows contradictory behaviour

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image: resonance of acetoxy group]

Why acetoxy group is ortho para directing and not meta directing?

Answer (score 3):

The first line in that image is an incorrect resonance structure. That the ester oxygen would have 4 bonds and a lone pair.

The bottom resonance structure is correct.

Comment: Why the first resonating structure is incorrect?? Would you please explain...

Comment: Got it...!!!  Thanx a lot..!!!